# How to create time-invariant variable using dplyr (R)

Tags: r

I have a dataset with two waves of data. I want to transform age to be time-invariant to take the value at time 2 for time 1. What is the best way to do this using `dplyr`?

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(ID = c(1001, 1001, 1002, 1002), time = c(1,2,1,2), age = c(23,25,54,56))
```

**Table:**

| ID | time | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 23 |
| 1001 | 2 | 25 |
| 1002 | 1 | 54 |
| 1002 | 2 | 56 |

**Desired Table:**

| ID | time | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 25 |
| 1001 | 2 | 25 |
| 1002 | 1 | 56 |
| 1002 | 2 | 56 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may do a group by 'ID' and get the `max` of 'age' in `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(age = max(age)) %>% 
   ungroup
```

---

Or if it should be from 'time' 2 - subset the 'age' based on logical expression with 'time', select the first element (also returns `NA` if there are no 'time' value of 2 for a particular 'ID'

```
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(age = age[time == 2][1]) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
     ID  time   age
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  1001     1    25
2  1001     2    25
3  1002     1    56
4  1002     2    56
```

---

Or another option is `arrange` the 'ID', 'time' and select the last element (assuming only 1 and 2 in 'time' and assuming all 'ID' have time 2)

```
df %>% 
   arrange(ID, time) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(age = last(age)) %>%
   ungroup
```

Comment: Thanks. For the second approach, can you explain what the `[1]` is doing in: `mutate(age = age[time == 2][1])`?

Comment: @VancityPlanner If you had `df$time[4] <- 5` i.e. ID 1002 doesn't have 'time' value of 2, then the logical expression returns all FALSE and thus it fails with `age[time == 2]`, by using `[1]`, it forces to add `NA` i.e. `v1 <- c(1, 3)'
v1[v1 == 2]#
numeric(0)` whereas `v1[v1 == 2][1]#
[1] NA`